# Prove that $\det(A) > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix such that : $A^{3} = A + \mathrm{I}_{n}$. Prove that $\det(A) > 0$.

Here is what I tried : $X^{3}-X-1$ is a null polynomial of $A$. As a consequence : $\mathrm{Sp}(A) \subset \left\{ \text{roots of } X^3-X-1 \right\}$. Let $\alpha$ be the only real root of $X^{3}-X-1$. By studying the variations of $x \, \mapsto \, x^{3}-x-1$, we can easily prove that $\alpha > 0$. Since $X^{3}-X-1$ has no other real root and is a real polynomial, if $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $X^3-X-1$, then $\overline{z}$ is a root too. As a consequence, $\left\{ \text{roots of } X^3 -X-1 \right\} = \left\{ \alpha, z, \overline{z} \right\}$. The determinant of $A$ is equal to the product of the eigenvalues of $A$ (with multiplicity).

If $\mathrm{Sp}(A) = \left\{ \alpha \right\}$, then $\det(A) = \alpha^{n} > 0$.

If $\mathrm{Sp}(A) = \left\{ \alpha, z, \overline{z} \right\}$, we must prove that $\overline{z}$ has the same multiplicity than $z$ (I'm not sure about this) so that : $\det(A) = \alpha^{m} \vert z \vert^{2p} > 0$ (where $m$ is the multiplicity of $\alpha$ in the characteristic polynomial and $p$ is the multiplicity of $z$).

If $\mathrm{Sp}(A) = \left\{ z, \overline{z} \right\}$, then $\det(A) = \vert z \vert^{n} > 0$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: What does $\;Sp(A)\;$ mean here?

Comment: @Timbuc : Here, $\mathrm{Sp}(A) = \left\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C}, \, A - \lambda \mathrm{I}_{n} \text{ is not invertible} \right\}$. It is the set of the complex eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: by *definition* only the complex ones? Not all the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Timbuc : Yes, all of them! The complex ones (real eigenvalues are also complex eigenvalues).

Comment: Well, yes...but then why to remark "complex"? :).

Comment: @Timbuc : Ok you're right, it is redundant. I just wanted to avoid the confusion between $\mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{R}}(A) = \left\{ \alpha \right\}$ and $\mathrm{Sp}_{\mathbb{C}}(A) = \left\{ \alpha,z, \overline{z} \right\}$.

Comment: @Timbuc the real numbers are a subset of the complex numbers

Comment: Really, @Omnomnomnom !? Well, I'll be... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea.

To prove multiplicity: it is a theorem that for any real polynomial $p(t)$, if $z$ is a root with multiplicity $p$, then so is $\overline{z}$.  Apply this to the polynomial $\det(A - tI)$.

Comment: Thanks ! Is it also correct to say that $\mathrm{Sp}(A) = \left\{ z, \overline{z} \right\}$ only if $n$ is even ? Because $z$ and $\overline{z}$ must have the same multiplicity...

Comment: Yes. Equivalently, every real polynomial of odd degree has a real root.

Answer (score 1):

From the eq. $A^3=A+I_n$ it readily follows that $A^{-1}=A^2-I_n$. That allows us to show first that $\det(A) \neq 0$. Moreover, from a straightforward application of the properties of determinants, we end up with the equality

$$\det(A-I_n)\det(A+I_n)=\frac{1}{\det(A)}.$$

**To prove that $det(A)>0$, one needs to employ a contradiction argument:** If one has that $det(A)<0$, by direct application of Bolzano theorem the auxiliar function $f(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I_n)$ (monic polynomial of degree $n$) has at least one [real] root, say $c$, on the open interval $]-1,1[$, since $f(1)f(-1)<0$. Moveover, for a given eigenpair $(c,v)$, one obtains the eigenvalue equation
$$ c^3 v =A^3v=(A+I_n)v=(c+1)v,$$
and whence, the equation $c^3=c+1$. This is turn allows us to show that $c^3$ is always positive, since $0<c+1<2$ (contradiction, because the inequality $-1<c<1$ implies $-1<c^3<1$?!).

Comment: The contradiction is not clear ! what if $0<c^3<1$ ?

Comment: To avoid ambiguities on the contradiction, we recall first that the condition $-1<c<1$ assures that $0<1-c^2<1$. This leads to 
$$-1=c-c^3=c(1-c^2)<c,$$
which is a contradiction, since the root of $f(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I_n)$ belong to the interval $]-1,1[$.

Comment: then what is the contradiction is not yet clear to me.

Comment: You are right! One notice that for $f(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I_n)$ the conditions $f(0)=det(A)<0$ and $f(-1)f(1)<0$ allows us to conclude that the root $c$ of $f(\lambda)$ belong to $(-1,0)$ or to $(0,1)$ (the case $c=0$ was excluded by the contradiction hypothesis).

The case $0<c<1$ is automatically excluded since $c(1-c^2)>0 >-1$. 

Thus, it remains clear that the root $c$ of $f$ must belong to the interval $-1<c<0$. Thus, the equation $c(1-c^2)=-1$ must be satisfied on the interval $(-1,0)$. This leads to $1>-c=\frac{1}{1-c^2}$, but $0<1-c^2<1$ implies that $\frac{1}{1-c^2}>1$.